# How can I use wildcards to remove repetition in my makefile?

Tags: makefile, chicken-scheme

I've got a makefile for Advent of Code that I've decided to do in chicken scheme.

However, it's starting to grow, and I'd like to remove the repetition.

Here's a section of what I've got so far, but how do I make it so it can automatically find all days instead of 2 entries per day and an ever increasing main target?

```
all: advent2015

# advent years - this is ever increasing with the *.so targets
advent2015: $(ADVENTS_SRC)2015/advent2015.scm \
 aoc2015day01.so aoc2015day02.so
    $(CSC) $(INCLUDE_FLAGS) $< -d3 -O2 -compile-syntax -o $@

# individual days - how do i write a single rule that works for all days?
aoc2015day01.so: $(ADVENTS_SRC)2015/aoc2015day01.scm aoc-files.so
    $(CSC) $(INCLUDE_FLAGS) $(LIBFLAGS) $< -j aoc2015day01 -emit-types-file aoc2015day01.types -o $@
    $(CSC) $(INCLUDE_FLAGS) $(IMPORTFLAGS) aoc2015day01.import.scm

aoc2015day01.import.so: aoc2015day01.so
    $(CSC) $(INCLUDE_FLAGS) $(IMPORTFLAGS) aoc2015day01.import.scm

# day02...
aoc2015day02.so: $(ADVENTS_SRC)2015/aoc2015day02.scm aoc-files.so
    $(CSC) $(INCLUDE_FLAGS) $(LIBFLAGS) $< -j aoc2015day02 -emit-types-file aoc2015day02.types -o $@
    $(CSC) $(INCLUDE_FLAGS) $(IMPORTFLAGS) aoc2015day02.import.scm

aoc2015day02.import.so: aoc2015day02.so
    $(CSC) $(INCLUDE_FLAGS) $(IMPORTFLAGS) aoc2015day02.import.scm
```

I tried a small change to the `advent2015` target by specifying a wildcard in the so files it is using, but make completely skipped generating the targets.

Comment: Well, `wildcard` will only find files that already exist on the disk.  If the file doesn't exist yet (because, for example, make is supposed to create it) then `wildcard` won't return it, just like running `ls` doesn't show it.

Comment: You don't really give enough information here.  You say _how do I make it so it can automatically find all days_ but you don't say what "all days" are, or how make is supposed to know what they are.  Do you mean you want to go up to 365?  If so, why do your days have only two digits (`01`, `02`, etc.)?  What are the source files; are they the `...scm` files?

Comment: sorry, when I say "all days", the puzzles go for 25 days, so there will be "aoc2015day01", "aoc2015day02", ... "aoc2015day25", which means I have to add 2 targets every time I add another day. But each target is the same apart from which day it is. e.g. "aoc2015day01.so" target is identical to "aoc2015day02" apart from referencing 02 instead of 01. I'd like to be able to use "%" in some way so I don't have to have 25 x 2 rules to cover every day.

Comment: ideally I could use a variable, e.g. "DAYS = 01 02 03" and then the rules could work over the list to create targets as needed, but I couldn't find the syntax that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem:

```
DAYS := 01 02 03 04 <...> 24 25

all: advent2015

advent2015: $(ADVENTS_SRC)2015/advent2015.scm \
     $(foreach D,$(DAYS),aoc2015day$(D).so)
        $(CSC) $(INCLUDE_FLAGS) $< -d3 -O2 -compile-syntax -o $@

%.so: $(ADVENTS_SRC)2015/%.scm aoc-files.so
        $(CSC) $(INCLUDE_FLAGS) $(LIBFLAGS) $< -j $* -emit-types-file $*.types -o $@
        $(CSC) $(INCLUDE_FLAGS) $(IMPORTFLAGS) $*.import.scm

%.import.so: %.so
        $(CSC) $(INCLUDE_FLAGS) $(IMPORTFLAGS) $*.import.scm
```

I'm not sure these commands are actually correct but they're what you provided above, so you can fix them if not.

Comment: works perfectly, thanks. There's a couple of extra places I'll be able to use this technique in my makefile, so just what I needed.

Comment: can you explain the SECONDEXPANSION here please @madscientist? I (accidentally) didn't include it and the build still worked for both clean and incremental build, so wondering if it's needed or I haven't come across why it's needed yet.

Comment: Oh sorry you don't need that.  I forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the [csm egg](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/5/csm) useful. I know it means getting rid of your makefile, but it should do the trick much more easily.

Alternatively, [beaker](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/5/beaker) provides ways of building based on `.egg` files, like those used by `chicken-install`.

Comment: csm might be an option. it can output makefile format too so I could find a way to combine it with the rest of the makefile. I will have a play. it would be nice to know if there is a native way to do this in makefile though for similar scenarios not specific to chicken